# Should you provide attribution for build tools

Tags: licensing

When providing a "credits" page or similar licensing information page listing any libraries distributed with your project, should you include builds tools such as Babel and Webpack?

Comment: What do you mean by *"distributed with"*?

Comment: Any third party NPM libraries you use are distributed with your application/website source code. Legally speaking, if you use a JavaScript library thats using an MIT license for example, you must provide attribution to the library.

Comment: What do the "terms of use" or license terms of those build tools say?

Comment: Why not give them a shout-out? They saved you time and the only "payment" they get for it is an infrequent 'Thanks!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any third party NPM libraries you use are distributed with your application/website source code. Legally speaking, if you use a JavaScript library thats using an MIT license for example, you must provide attribution to the library.

I think you are mixing a few things:

1. Third party libraries vs. build tools.
2. Licensing terms vs. attribution of credits.

#### Third party libraries vs. build tools

Let's say you use some third party libraries to build your application. These will be used by the user of your application when they run your application. Your users must agree to the licensing terms if your application as well as the third party libraries.

Now, let's say you use some third party build tools to build your application. These won't be used by the user when they run your application. Your users must agree to the licensing terms of your application but not the build tools.

#### Licensing terms vs. attribution of credits

When a third party library is included in your applications, the licensing terms should be sufficient. If the licensing terms require credit attribution, then you attribute credit accordingly.

From a stand point of principle, you shouldn't have to provide any licensing terms for your users for your build tools. After all, they don't use it when they use your application. However, your build tool provider might require you to provide credit attribution when you distribute your software as part of the licensing agreement of using their tools.